# Adding Secondary Data file in SQL Always on

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

How to add the Secondary Data file to the Database which is a part of Always on availability Group in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it as you would normally do on the primary node. Make sure that all the nodes have the same disk configuration and enough disk space.